# JavaScript error 'StackExchange.ready is not a function' when visiting stackexchange.com

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, userscript

This is a bug. I try to view another site, and it works fine, but I have a problem on Stack Exchange.

[image]

[image]

Details:

1. I open this URL: https://stackexchange.com/ and open the console.
2. After a few seconds, I get the pictured error.
3. Last version of Windows 10, and the last version of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is not a bug Stack Exchange has to fix. They can't be held responsible to prevent bugs in scripts they don't own.

Instead report the bug to the creator and/or current maintainer here: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) or even better: create a pull request with a fix for this bug.

Or do as I have done for the last 6 to 8 years: ignore that console error. It only happens on sites where no global `StackExchange` object gets created (and/or it doesn't have the expected public interface). Most notable those are: stackexchange.com and all chat servers. Nothing will break despite that error.

In the comments you're claiming that you don't have userscripts or extensions. Here is a screenshot of my Firefox console where I have no extensions or scripts running:

[image]

and here is my Chrome dev console, with Autocomments and a bunch of other scripts:

[image]

Try your browser in Incognito or Private mode and see how it goes.

Comment: On an off-note, stackexchange.com *does* have a global object `StackExchange`, it's just that it does not have a `ready` lifecycle method at all (as a bunch of others); [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXULP.png) which is exactly what the console says to the OP: ".ready is not a function" :)