# "add comment" & "show more comment" no longer working on android tablet with firefox

Tags: support, comments, mobile-firefox

Since a couple of days I'm no longer able to view more than 5 comments nor to add one myself.  This happens on two different up to date android tablets, one with an older firefox (the last one allowing about:config), the other with nightly.

Any idea what changed on the site last week?

Comment: Before reading your link, just want to mention that I posted this question using Seamonkey.  My answer to that would thus be "no".  I use Seamonkey full-time on StackExchange.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console? There have been changes made to the site's Javascript, that was the reason SeaMoneky stopped working.

Comment: How does one open the console on Android Firefox?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running on that Android tablet?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille one would need use of a desktop/laptop it appears: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/08/remote-debugging-on-firefox-for-android/

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson for reading my post before commenting.  I'm afraid it's a 68.  Can't check the nightly currently.  In the mean time I found https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372734/was-support-for-the-seamonkey-browser-just-removed#comment1244916_372734, where it says "fixed" ?

Comment: @Luuklag, I'll be sure to give that a try this afternoon, looks an interesting exercise.

Comment: Does clicking on the vote count to see the breakdown between up- and downvotes work for you btw?

Comment: It doesn't, the timeline does, and clicking on my inbox often gives me my profile (even when the URL says tab=inbox).  Someone at SE must be enjoying h(er/im)self.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/361484 for the reasoning behind all this (probably)

Comment: @Luuklag, that's the same as in my comment above ... 'where it says "fixed"'.

Comment: Pff, remotedebugging, had to install a desktop version 68, which upgraded faster than I could disable it. The fifth time I installed it as root, which prevented that carroussel.  The console shows: "TypeError: l.replaceAll is not a function", stub.en.js:1.861.

Comment: At position 686 I see "l=function(e,t,n,o){...}"  while replaceAll expects it to be a string prototype.

Comment: LOL.  Closed because "this question already exists", pointing to a question added 15 hours after mine, 6 hours after I found the cause.  I'm good, but not clairvoyant.

Answer (score 4):

replaceAll needs a newer javascript engine.  On Android eg., it needs at least Firefox version 79.  See [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).  It mentions that core.js has a polyfill for that function.