# JavaScript no longer works all of a sudden

Tags: bug, javascript, browsers

Since today it seems like almost all buttons on the site have href="#". When I click on them, the page just jumps up, but nothing else.

For example:

- the 'more hot questions' link
- the hamburger menu top left
- show more comments
- make a new comment
- votes
- can't ask questions

I use SE almost only at work and the Firefox browser I use is the latest for the Windows on this system, and I can't install a newer version. I'm using Firefox 52.9.0.

I don't really understand why an older browser doesn't work anymore now.

Comment: TL;DR: the code was just updated to make use of optional chaining, which helps to shorten it and make it more maintainable. Unfortunately, that was only introduced in Firefox 74 (ESR 78).

Comment: https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/ unlikely anything could be done about this...

Comment: I'm not sure, I think SeaMonkey is an other browser?

Comment: Thank you sonic for explaining the thing with this chaining. I'm just sad that I now can't use SE anymore

Comment: The cause is the same. As the user agent string indicates, it's based on Firefox 68.

Comment: @undefined you can, with a newer browser. :)

Comment: Firefox has a portable version that might solve your problem.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Is Vaccinated V3 but I can't install a newer browser because it's the latest version I can install for the windows on this office computer

Comment: @undefined oh, I see now. Well that's indeed a problem, but sadly SE can't flex for such cases. Only tip I can give is browse from your phone, they improved the mobile experience a lot in recent months.

Comment: @Mast I tried potable Firefox and Chrome but sadly both won't run. I think it's because of the older windows.

Comment: I posted a request at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372769 .

Comment: Re *"the Firefox browser I use is the latest for the Windows on this system ...Firefox 52.9.0"*: Is that the pre-[Quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(software)#Quantum) version? [52.0 is from 2017-03-07](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_52_through_59). The current version of Firefox is 94.0.

Comment: @P.Mort. - forgot Clay Shirky_q I think that's long before quantum. In the about it says "Firefox ESR 52.9.0"

Comment: Thats an extended supoort release. My cimaony also runs those. We are at 91.3.0 ESR, so you are (light)years behind and probably very vulnerable to allnsorts if attacks that have since been patched. Cc @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q

Comment: @Luuklag thank you. But it's the latest browser I can install on this OS and the latest that will run on this windows version. Even the newer portable ones won't run

Comment: Well then its definetly time for an upgrade. Your workplace is taking a lot of risk running outdated hard and software.

Comment: @Luuklag it's a windows server 2003. And the company won't change that. And I can't influence this either

Comment: @Ulrich Diez take a look at the answer and the comments  from Emil Jeřábek https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372769 there everything is kinda explained. Basically they say your/our browser is too old and it's our fault for using old software