# Script error: Missing polyfill for replaceAll

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript

***This is a bug report for Stack Exchange frontend code (sstatic.net); don't close it as off-topic!***

**Script error: Missing polyfill for replaceAll**

On older browsers, the site is broken. I can't click on any button. There is no `String.prototype.replaceAll`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility

There is an error on this script here:

https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=17e20b4b4731

```
Uncaught TypeError: l.replaceAll is not a function
    at a (stub.en.js?v=17e20b4b4731:formatted:55)
    at full.en.js?v=3708f79bf934:formatted:2365
    at Object.266 (full.en.js?v=3708f79bf934:formatted:2493)
    at __webpack_require__ (full.en.js?v=3708f79bf934:formatted:11524)
    at a (full.en.js?v=3708f79bf934:formatted:138)
    at e (full.en.js?v=3708f79bf934:formatted:11676)
    at full.en.js?v=3708f79bf934:formatted:11684
    at full.en.js?v=3708f79bf934:formatted:11726
    at full.en.js?v=3708f79bf934:formatted:11728
```

`babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3@0.2.5` needs to be updated. See String.prototype.replaceAll not polyfilled #13701:

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/13701#issuecomment-925119447

Comment: Probably related to this: [JavaScript no longer works all of a sudden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372766/401803) | [We're Migrating our JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/401803)

Comment: @hkotsubo Yea, it's probably because of that site JS update.

Comment: I can confirm that adding a `replaceAll` polyfill fixes the website. It's a simple fix. No other script errors. Works in old browsers again.

Comment: @XP1, what took you so long?  ["add comment" & "show more comment" no longer working on android tablet with firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372900/add-comment-show-more-comment-no-longer-working-on-android-tablet-with-fir)  ;-)

Comment: @XP1, how does one add such a PolyFill?  From the console?

Comment: Test snippet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: Just deployed a fix, should be sorted now. Let me know if you continue to have problems.

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille, I noticed something was wrong (couldn't vote) a few days ago, but I was too lazy to investigate. I assumed a major website would have this fixed before I would. :S Adding the polyfill in the console wouldn't work unless it was done before the script loads. It would have to be a user script or extension that loads before the script. However, what I did differently was intercept the HTTPS traffic and inject my own modified JS file instead of using the server's JS file. I used Fiddler web debugging proxy, so all browsers will receive my modified JS. No need console or extension.

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson, thanks, currently typing in my old browser. :)

Comment: @XP1 if you use Chrome, it can be as simple as adding a local override in the meantime too