# JS broken on older web browsers due to undefined 'globalThis'

Tags: bug, status-review, javascript

It seems a recent change in StackExchange has rendered it no longer working correctly on my browser (Firefox 60.7esr). The error message is:

> ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined

[image: Web page console]

As a result, most actions that requiring JS support such as voting, expanding comments, and leaving comment, has stopped working on affected browsers.

Can StackExchange add a fallback mechanism to support such silently older browsers? May be a polyfill of `globalThis` implemented at https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/globalthis?

Comment: Yeah, result of [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372590/were-migrating-our-javascript). :/

Comment: related: [Script error: Missing polyfill for replaceAll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372933/script-error-missing-polyfill-for-replaceall) and [Was support for the SeaMonkey browser just removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372734/was-support-for-the-seamonkey-browser-just-removed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script error: Missing polyfill for replaceAll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372933/script-error-missing-polyfill-for-replaceall)

Comment: @DonaldDuck while the browser is unsupported this was introduced by the latest javascript changes. As with similar bugs these have been acted in. No need to close as a dupe.

Comment: @Rob this is certainly related, but a different error, so not a dupe IMHO.

Comment: As a note, I can workaround this issue by quickly evaluating that polyfill in the console, right after I triggering a reload of the affected page. Therefore I can still post this comment using the old browser.