# Why doesn't the privacy popup go away? Can you fix it?

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, privacy

I sometimes have a popup that shows up and refuses to go.

[image]

Regardless what button I click it doesn't react.  It just stays and covers part of the page.  I have to resort to ctrl-shift-C to remove it.  Is it possible to fix that behaviour?

**More info**

I am seeing this in Waterfox v. 56.2.8 (64-bit).
I am running Windows 10 (version 1809) in French.

The problem seems to go away when I log in.  When I clear all cookies it comes back.

I looked at the web console but no warning or error when I click.  However, when I reload the page, I can see some errors but no clue whether they are related to the problem or not.

[image]

Comment: Related: [The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/the-cookie-consent-dialog-coming-from-cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up)

Comment: @Emil Thanks.  It gives some useful info.  But in my case, clicking a button does nothing.  It is not that it comes back, it just doesn't budge.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: There is literally nothing in your post that would enable diagnosing the problem. To begin with, what version of what browser on what OS are you using? Do you use any add-ons or userscripts?

Comment: I first wanted to make sure this is the right place.  But I will complete the information.  It was also possible you have seen this before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS broken on older web browsers due to undefined 'globalThis'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374312/js-broken-on-older-web-browsers-due-to-undefined-globalthis) (see also: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/369403), Waterfox isn't officially supported, nor is Firefox v56, there's a chance they'll accommodate them but I wouldn't count on it)

Comment: It somehow answers the question.  Any chance that it will get fixed?

Comment: A staffer marked it status-review, so maybe. I don't know. If they rejected the idea of fixing it outright, it would've been marked status-declined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you've already discovered this, but I'll throw it here anyway:

Someone else may be able to offer workarounds, but unfortunately the official "answer" to this is that **you're using a browser that is both unsupported** (it's not on [the formal browser support list](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/)), **and quite old** by web standards (I had to go digging– [Waterfox v56.2.8 was released March 14, 2019](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112015937/https://www.waterfox.net/blog/waterfox-56.2.8-release-download/)).

Even just from a security standpoint, you should likely update to a [more recent version](https://www.waterfox.net/)**, which may address the issue (though Waterfox appears to have changed hands, which may or may not sit well with some users of this browser), or switch to something else that's more up to date on security updates and other features.

---

* <sup>- Your Waterfox version identifies as Firefox v60, *36* versions behind current FF (v96).</sup>
** <sup>- A "classic" edition of Waterfox also [appears to be available](https://classic.waterfox.net/), for older systems, though the download page notes that it may contain unaddressed security advisories, and it may or may not support the modern JavaScript features required to fix the issue here.</sup>

Comment: Thank you.  It is all my fault, then...