# Core functionalities broken by a site update

Tags: bug, javascript

A change near CE 2021-12-17 22:00 UTC has caused the core JavaScript based functionalities (comments loading, posting, etc.) cease to work on Chrome 77: rendering the site pretty much unusable on this very platform afterward.

The site appeared to be working normally with Firefox 95 though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We're Migrating our JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372590/were-migrating-our-javascript)

Comment: That version of Chrome is unsupported - the current oldest [supported version](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) is 95

Comment: Close voters: **" Rather than posting bug reports as answers to this post, in this case we'd prefer you to post a separate question for each bug you find."**.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 then this should be closed as lacking details, as there is nothing here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Luuklag so we need to ask for such details to be added.

Comment: @StockExchange can you please add the error messages you get from your Chrome console to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 77 is a "very" old version. According to https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/, as of December 19th, the latest version is 96, by the other hand, according to https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/ as of December 20th that version is unsupported.

Try using an up to date and supported web browser.

Reference

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/browser-support