# The PGN Viewer (replayer) stopped working on Chess Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, javascript, specific-site

On [Chess Stack Exchange](https://chess.stackexchange.com/), there is a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/andrewphoy/chess-replayer) which is integrated to display diagrams like this:

[image: chess-replayer screenshot]

Today (1 February 2022), at around the time when [this chess question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39117/why-is-forking-the-king-and-rook-a-blunder-in-this-halloween-gambit-line) was first posted, the PGN Viewer plugin stopped working across the whole site. The issue seems to be reproducible on all devices and browsers.

Instead of the chess diagram, we now see a code block with the chess notation instead:

[image: Question with chess diagram screenshot]

There is a console error on all pages of the Chess SE and Chess SE Meta websites:

[image: Console error]

In [We're Migrating our JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372590/were-migrating-our-javascript), we were asked to post separate questions for bugs related to the JavaScript migration, so I am posting this question.

There is also a question about this on Chess Meta SE: [Why has the PGN Viewer (replayer) stopped working?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/why-has-the-pgn-viewer-replayer-stopped-working)

Comment: That plugin was migrated a few weeks ago, so it sounds like something new broke that ended up affecting it. We'll take a look, thanks for the report!

Comment: It is working for me right now (I didn't make any changes, just went to check it out). Can you reproduce the error? Extensions off? Browser and version?

Comment: @YaakovEllis Not working FF 96.3.0 for Android 10, nor FF 97.0 (64-bit) for Win11 Pro, nor Edge Version 97.0.1072.76 (Official build) (64-bit). Adblocker and extensions disabled.

Comment: Potentially worth noting I get different errors in each browser: https://justpaste.it/9jme9. Post used for testing: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39117/why-is-forking-the-king-and-rook-a-blunder-in-this-halloween-gambit-line. Tested both signed in and signed out.

Comment: @AdamLear Was any fix done? For me, it's working on desktop now (Chrome, Edge, Firefox). It's not working on mobile (both browser and app), but that might have been an existing issue. I see some people saying that it does not work for them on desktop though.

Comment: @hb20007 FWIW, it is still not working for me in neither Edge nor FF.

Comment: It is working for me on all desktop browsers (tried on latest Chrome, Edge, FF). Not working for me on laterst Android Chrome.

Comment: @YaakovEllis It might not have been working on phone browsers originally: https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363/pgn-viewer-support-on-mobile-phones

Comment: @hb20007 good call. When I use in mobile chrome and switch to full desktop, it works. So looking like a long-standing issue with chess plugin itself not working on mobile view, not something new.

Comment: @Nick It seems that most people cannot reproduce the issue on desktop anymore. Can you try on a new Private/Incognito window or on a different machine if you happen to have one?

Comment: @hb20007 Sure, I've just tried incognito on my work laptop, FF96.0.3 (64-bit) still has the same issue, as does Edge 97 and Chrome 98. Potentially region/ISP related?

Comment: Reproduced in FF 96.0.2 (64 bit) on Linux Mint

Comment: I can reproduce it (`Chrome 97.0.4692.99` on `Windows 11 Version 21H2` with incognito mode) when I use no VPN but it works with a VPN (or with some VPN locations) for me.

Comment: @YaakovEllis bit working for me on desktop/vivaldi (almost the same as chrome), on desktop view. As nick suggests, it might be regional / an issue with specific servers getting hit?

Comment: @YaakovEllis FWIW, I was able to reproduce this last night before I status-reviewed. Chrome desktop on Win10.

Comment: I think this _could_ be due to a webpack bug, though I haven't been able to narrow it down to a minimal repro. I'm working on getting a workaround out the door, ETA some time in the next couple of hours. Apologies for the inconvenience, and thanks for reporting!

Comment: Looks like we're back up and running again. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson (y) Looks good to me

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson It would be interesting to know what the issue was at a high level if you want to share.

Comment: I think it was a Webpack bug. The `chess` code is set up to be loaded dynamically by the Webpack runtime system, but it had also been configured as an (unused) [entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) in the Webpack config. As far as I know that's meant to be supported, and I couldn't reproduce it when I ran the build on my machine, but removing the entry point for the `chess` code does seem to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be fixed now. I think it was a Webpack bug. The `chess` code is set up to be loaded dynamically by the Webpack runtime system, but it had also been configured as an (unused) [entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) in the Webpack config. As far as I know that's meant to be supported, and I couldn't reproduce it when I ran the build on my machine, but removing the entry point for the `chess` code does seem to have fixed the issue.

Thank you again for reporting the bug!