# Inline tag editing does not work

Tags: bug, 500-server-error, inline-tag-editor

When I try to edit the tags of a question inline, I get an error message:

> An error occurred when fetching the tag editor

[image: Screenshot showing the error message in a pop-up next to the tags]

I have tried both clicking on "Edit tags" and the keyboard shortcut <kbd>t</kbd> - both act the same.

In the network tab I see
that a request to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71202402/edit-tags?_=1645432229405 returns a 500 response.

This seems to be a recent issue. The last time I have used the inline tag editing was at 2022-02-21 0700:39Z: [link for revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71202305/2)

I am using Firefox 97.0 on Windows.

Comment: Is that the same as https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376282/369802? In that case, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376282/after-clicking-the-edit-tags-link-a-pop-up-appears-an-error-occurred-when-f#comment1254435_376282 ..

Comment: Unable to reproduce here on this site. I just used the inline tag editor to add the [tag:500-server-error] tag to this question, and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Rob that wasn't an inline edit.

Comment: No idea if it's the same cause as the other report. It's happening on desktop and Catja's comment suggests it's a mobile issue. I don't know whether there is a link or a new issue. I'm leaving this open for the moment, as I cannot confirm nor deny it's the same as the suggested dupe.

Comment: OK...this is stupid then - it *is* linked. I accidentally clicked "Mobile" in the footer earlier. I thought I turned it off by clicking again. But turns out clicking the "Mobile" link in the footer ***ONLY TURNS MOBILE ON EVERY TIME YOU CLICK!*** So, I had to use JS in the console to disable it: `StackExchange.switchMobile("off")` which did fix the problem. I'd consider the link not working as a toggle a bug but it's soon to be removed, no point posting it.

Comment: [That](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376461/inline-tag-editing-does-not-work#comment1254822_376461) is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376343/282094).

Comment: @VLAZ No need to post, someone did that too https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376343/369802 :D

Comment: The [duplicate on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416088/edit-tags-not-working-and-comment-flag-icon-missing-in-mobile#comment895455_416088) says it's [tag:status-planned].