# Post notices are not instantly displayed

Tags: bug, post-notices

I think within the last day or two a new bug has arisen: when a mod applies a post notice, it is not instantly displayed to them. Instead the mod must refresh the page to see it. This is quite confusing, and several times I've thought it didn't work and then tried to add a post notice a second time. The system does know that it is applied though, because the mod menu then says "remove notice" rather than "add notice".

There's an error in the browser console, beginning with

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"Html":"            \r\n\r\n  \r\n<a name="89699">\r\n<div id="answer-89699"

Comment: Is there an error in the browser console? Very likely related: [Loading posts in real time is broken in some cases due to a breaking change in the format data is returned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376823/289905).

Comment: "the mod must refresh..." Caching?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The post notices used to be added by Javascript, and now aren't. I don't see how caching could affect this. And the fact that the mod menu knows that a post notice is applied shows that caching hasn't prevent the browser from seeing the result of applying it the first time.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Good thinking, yes there is an error.

Comment: @curiousdannii Ah, yes, that looks like the same bug!

Comment: Probably caused at the same time, but the solution may not be the same. I wouldn't close this as a duplicate, but would wait for staff to confirm whether it is or not.

Comment: @curiousdannii I’m pretty sure the cause and potential solution are identical. JSON like `{ "Html": "`…`" }` is being passed to jQuery rather than the HTML itself, causing this error; this is due to a recent API change.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Right, but assuming they don't just revert the API, then fixing it will require fixing it every time the API is consumed. If this question is closed as a duplicate then it may not get the attention of the developers when they fix the reloading posts issue. Or it may be that the JS which applies post notices does call the post reloader, in which case it is a true duplicate. The staff can let us know which it is.

Comment: Rather than posting bug reports as answers to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/282094), in this case we'd prefer you to post a **separate question** for ***each*** bug you find. - Dec 7, 2021 at 16:02 Benjamin Hodgson [Staff][Mod]. --- So there's a slight preference for dupes, if there's any chance this isn't one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading posts in real time is broken in some cases due to a breaking change in the format data is returned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376823/loading-posts-in-real-time-is-broken-in-some-cases-due-to-a-breaking-change-in-t)

Comment: Is this still happening, or should it be marked as [status-completed] per the linked Q&As?