# Editor in "Ask Question" page has two snippet icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, markdown, stack-snippets

There are two snippet icons displayed in the question's body Markdown editing tool. Clicking on both icons opens the snippet section.

I am able to reproduce this on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Two snippet icons - image]

**GIF for reference:**

[image: Two snippet icons - gif]

Comment: No repo for me at LawSE nor LawMetaSE, but I can repo it here so it seems this has a limited distribution (Android, Samsung Galaxy)

Comment: Reproduced in MSE, Firefox 104.1.0, Android 12 (only visible in ask question page, not in answer box)

Comment: @RandomPerson well oddly enough when you ask a question and choose to answer it in same time (ticking the "Answer your own question" checkbox"), you also get the bugged editor.

Comment: See also on MSO: [I see two snippet buttons in the editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420175/i-see-two-snippet-buttons-in-the-editor)

Comment: balpha already wrote a fix, awaiting push to production in about a day. (See the MSO post)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>(cross-posting from [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420175/i-see-two-snippet-buttons-in-the-editor/420249#420249))</sub>

Fixed now, thanks!

[Catija's theory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420175/i-see-two-snippet-buttons-in-the-editor#comment925233_420175) was correct, my fix for the missing [CircuitLab button](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/circuit-editor-missing-from-ask-question-page) also fixed underlying cause of the [missing snippet button issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381279/who-sniped-the-snippet), so that problem was suddenly fixed twice and thus you got two buttons.

Comment: Glad there's finally legit reason for you to have diamond here, and not just in chat. :D