# Snippet button missing on Staging Ground question creation

Tags: bug, status-review, stack-snippets, stacks-editor, staging-ground

I've been wondering why there is no 'create snippet' button when asking a question on Stack Overflow!

[image: Missing create snippet button]

I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381279/who-sniped-the-snippet) meta post asking where it was 7 months ago and staff mentioned that it was being worked on. Since then it appears we have an identical button that only creates a code block.

I volunteer a large portion of my time editing questions into snippets so that they can be answered faster, I always wondered why people didn't just use a snippet when writing their question - well no wonder! I know you can copy paste the snippet markup but most people would have no idea.
Is there any way I can help to get this added?

Comment: Ah I missed that part.  I guess the old editor is what I use.  I don't have those options to switch to markdown etc. in the top right.  I'm also not opted into the beta.  This is how mine looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bB7n.png

Comment: Oh maybe it's A/B testing? How do I switch to the old editor

Comment: @ZachJensz it's not A/B testing. From the screenshot, it seems you're using the Ask Wizard [which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzYDu.png) (and itself uses the new editor). As opposed to the [non-wizard ask page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gx12.png) which uses the old (current) editor. New users are forced into the wizard (not sure what the cutoff to clear that - maybe X questions or X rep). Other users are allowed to opt in and out - [there is a toggle at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIGzg.png).

Comment: @VLAZ "_For users with at least one previous well-received question asked on the site, or three previous questions asked, there will be a toggle above the Title section allowing the user to toggle between the Ask Wizard and the existing Ask experience._" ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421038/11107541))

Comment: The current button to create a code block should instead create a snippet, because that's what the icon means for the old editor, that everyone who is able to use, uses.