# I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: Stacks is not defined" errors in my browser console on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, javascript

The last few weeks the amount of 'Stacks is not defined' errors is increasing.

---

This *occasionally* occurs on any StackExchange site, and throws the following error in the console <sup>[[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LauTs.png)</sup>:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Stacks is not defined
    at 63972 (full.en.js?v=5e227002b176:1:111277)
    at __webpack_require__ (full.en.js?v=5e227002b176:1:280143)
    at a (full.en.js?v=5e227002b176:1:2046)
    at e (full.en.js?v=5e227002b176:1:286056)
    at full.en.js?v=5e227002b176:1:286451
    at full.en.js?v=5e227002b176:1:289460
    at full.en.js?v=5e227002b176:1:289464
```

File that causes this error:
`full.en.js?v=5e227002b176`

When the error is thrown, the complete page stops responding, buttons won't work but no error is shown <sup>[[2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1jv.gif)</sup>.

---

I'm not aware of any plugins that might cause this.

Since this is getting quite annoying, I'd love a bug-fix, or an explanation of why this might happen.

---

Browser: Google Chrome, Version `105.0.5195.125` (Official Build) (x86_64)

<sup>1: [Google Chrome Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LauTs.png)</sup>
<sup>2: [GIF showing the error + unresponsive page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1jv.gif)</sup>

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this. I opened dev tools on this page as well as on a random question on SO and I don't see the message. Tried FF but also Chrome 106 where I don't have any extensions.

Comment: It's probably not something you can force. I encounter a non-working page like 4/5 times a day, then the error is shown in the Console, f5, and the page works fine. So you might need some 'luck' to reproduce this. I can share a screen recording if that might help?

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realise it was intermittently showing up.

Comment: OK, I sat and did 20-30 refreshes in a row. Still no luck in reproducing it. However, if it happens intermittently, it might be stale cached resources on one of the CDNs. Which you might only get occasionally. Moreover, it might be location-specific which servers will respond to your request.

Comment: Yea, I don't think you will be able to force it. Anyway, I just reloaded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74031238/reusable-components-in-react) question, and the issue came up, site unresponsive. Error is the same. Unfortunately the 'network' tab was not open, so can't see the request which might give some useful info. Issue remains! [Gif showing error + unresponsive page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1jv.gif)

Comment: Bug in the image occurs in `_Scripts/LegacyJS/full-common/controllers/se-char-counter.js`. It assumes `Stacks` (the top-level entry object for the SO design system) is available but by the looks of it, the Stacks js gets loaded async in the head of the page so it might not have yet been initialized when full.en.js runs the code. That would explain the intermittent nature of the bug. For reference: http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js

Comment: Should be possible to solve that with JavaScript's `Promise` API, or the fancy new `await` keyword.

Comment: @rene Gold star! That is exactly what is going on here. Chrome and FireFox end up in a race condition that is sometimes fatal but Safari always ends up in a fatal error (for some reason). We've got a PR ready to test and review that'll be going out early next week.

Comment: Another side-effect, when the bug occurs, hovering over the title, trigger the request to fetch [this favicon sprite](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=9e298e5b472b), a lot of times. Not sure if that is a separate issue. [Picture after hovering over the title a few times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxmrX.png).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shout out to [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) for correctly identifying the cause of the problem! So what happened? Here's a little bit of history and description of the problem.

Prior to starting our [migration to Webpack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372590/were-migrating-our-javascript), we relied on `stub.js` to import the Stacks JavaScript asynchronously because we did not want it to be a blocking operation on page load. After we started our migration, we took that logic out of `stub.js` and replaced it with a `<script async>` tag. Why `async`? Well, `stub.js` was loading it asynchronously, so why wouldn't we follow the same behavior? After all, it hadn't caused us problems up until this point.

Any new JavaScript that we are writing is largely being written as JS modules; for example, the new Saves functionality was written as a module and made use of Stacks' utility functions (e.g. [`hidePopover`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/blob/db3b9bd0448dbc1359fceccb1e89aaaf99d0c3a6/lib/ts/controllers/s-popover.ts#L404-L421)). However, we still have a lot of old code that has yet to be migrated so we can't bundle Stacks into our page entry points because not every page has an entry point yet. So, we must keep Stacks being loaded as a `<script>` and have configured Webpack to not bundle Stacks but to look at the `window` variable for a `Stacks` object.

Why did this start causing problems now? Race conditions! Our new JS bundles code relies on Stacks helper functions and if Stacks is not loaded (remember, it's `async`), then you'll get that undefined error. For whatever reason, this error was always fatal on Safari but it was only sometimes fatal on Chrome and Firefox.

What did we change? Stacks is now being loaded via `<script defer>` allowing it to be downloaded after the page has finished loading but before our bundles require Stacks to exist.

Lastly, why did it take us so long to push out the fix if it was just a simple change from `async` to `defer`? Testing is hard! We wanted to be comfortable that this change wasn't going to cause performance or technical issues. Also, bribing our devs with Macs to test takes a lot of negotiating!